# Python: Overshoot target, need vectors or PID tuning?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vector

So, i'm working with a UAV, and I want to place it in the center between two objects, however, the UAV will overshoot the move operation, then proceed to go back to the center in the opposite direction, overshoot again and do this endlessly. 
Is there a way to compensate, or use some sort of PID that would make it not overshoot the center?

To view what that looks like live:
[UAV cant center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pw1Hn.jpg)

Code I use now:

```
if (sensor.left > sensor.right):
    velocity_x = 0.2
    print('Moving left')
if (sensor.left < sensor.right):
    velocity_x = -0.2
    print('Moving right')
if (sensor.left == sensor.right):
    velocity_x = 0

uav.move(velocity_x,velocity_y)
```

Any suggestions how to get it to stay more stable?
I believe vectors would be more appropriate to keep it stable, but have no reference point on what to use. I saw some tutorials online that used vectors, but they suffered from the same "overshoot" issue.

Below is an output of the sensors and debugging info:
n center, stopping!
In center, reversing velocity!

```
front=1.924
back=0.66
left=0.516
right=0.447
Moving left
Front = 1.924 
Back = 0.66 
Left = 0.516 
Right = 0.447 
Vel X = 0.0 
Vel Y = 0.1 
--------------------------------
front=1.926
back=0.669
left=0.525
right=0.445
Moving left
Front = 1.926 
Back = 0.669 
Left = 0.525 
Right = 0.445 
Vel X = 0.0 
Vel Y = 0.1 
--------------------------------
front=1.921
back=0.668
left=0.535
right=0.445
Moving left
Front = 1.921 
Back = 0.668 
Left = 0.535 
Right = 0.445 
Vel X = 0.0 
Vel Y = 0.1 
--------------------------------
front=1.912
back=0.676
left=0.54
right=0.443
Moving left
Front = 1.912 
Back = 0.676 
Left = 0.54 
Right = 0.443 
Vel X = 0.0 
Vel Y = 0.1
```

Comment: as I see in the video and noticed in the code, the UAV is going back and forth in a single direction which I think is because of that `+0.2,-0.2`. maybe you could assign that relatively and make it decent over time. maybe you can use the difference between `sensor.left` and `sensor.right` to adjust it.

Comment: Depending on distance it changes value of velocity to + or - 0.2. Plus makes it go left, minus right.

Comment: how low of a velocity can you give it? i would just have the velocity scale with the difference between the sensor values. that way its velocity will decrease at it gets closer to the center

Comment: So what happens is, it goes left, get's to the cener,  still has momentum, overshoots, then tries to correct by going back with -0.2. Should do something with vectors where it would compensate prior to reaching the point by reducing the speed or perhaps adding backwards thrust for a sec to make it stop.

Comment: what i'm saying is you should scale the velocity based on how far away it is from the center. that way as it gets closer and closer to the center it'll slow down and not overshoot.

Comment: also i would take a look at what values those sensors are returning, it might be unrealistic to say that the UAV is only at center if `sensor.left` equals `sensor.right`. consider defining an acceptable amount of difference between those two values instead of demanding they be precisely equal

Comment: Here's an example:
n center, stopping!
In center, reversing velocity!
front=1.924
back=0.66
left=0.516
right=0.447
Moving left
Front = 1.924 
Back = 0.66 
Left = 0.516 
Right = 0.447 
Vel X = 0.0 
Vel Y = 0.1 
--------------------------------
front=1.926
back=0.669
left=0.525
right=0.445
Moving left
Front = 1.926 
Back = 0.669 
Left = 0.525 
Right = 0.445 
Vel X = 0.0 
Vel Y = 0.1 
--------------------------------
front=1.921
back=0.668
left=0.535
right=0.445
Moving left
Front = 1.921 
Back = 0.668 
Left = 0.535 
Right = 0.445 
Vel X = 0.0 
Vel Y = 0.1

Comment: @R0b0tn1k would you please update your question with data in recent comment to be more readable.

Comment: Added debug info in the question, as I cant do markup in comments.

Comment: I still think we're approaching this wrong. Last night I gave it some thought. We should add both distances together to get the length (left + right = length). Target = length / 2. Then I know how much I have left to target by substracting the lower value or left or right (whichever is closer). Then I just do some vector math and stop one length of the vehicle before.

Comment: @R0b0tn1k have you tried my proposed work around ?

Comment: Yes, I did, a couple of times until I exhausted both batteries. All times the result was the same. It would move left and crash in the wall. I'm telling you the approach is wrong. I realized the reason why it's wiggling it's because of acceleration. Although I set this to 0, the UAV still has acceleration from the counter operation, and even with the optical flow sensor it's too low to detect. Therefore I must counter it before the stopping point or minimize it. So at some point before the center I actually have to invert velocity for a sec so it comes to a full stop.

Comment: Btw, here's the output from your code:
https://pastebin.com/XDGaUvJm

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like this will work depending on hardware limitation to accept value ranges, the code goes like this:

```
if (sensor.left > sensor.right):
    velocity_x = 0.2/i    #<====
    print('Moving left to center')
if (sensor.left < sensor.right):
    velocity_x = -0.2/i   #<====
    print('Moving right to center')
if (sensor.left == sensor.right):
    velocity_x = 0
i+=0.1 # i initial value is equal to 1 <====
uav.move(velocity_x,velocity_y)
```

or might want to change your last if statement, because expecting those sensors in the real world to be exactly equal is not fair.

```
from __experimental__ import approx
if (sensor.left ~= sensor.right):
    velocity_x = 0
```

It depends on your python version to use this Approximately equal operator, but you can do it in a little function and use it in your conditional statement.